# Mega sync client freezes hangs turns off after sleep suspend

Tags: gnome, suspend, crash, mega

The title says it all, I have gnome shell, ubuntu 15.04, when I wake up, the indicator is still on, I right click, I push open and mega disappears while the windows doesnt get open but the process is still on so I need to go to system monitor, kill the process and relaunch the mega sync client only after that. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

kill the megasync process

`killall megasync`

Remove your old configurations and

`rm -rf /home/john/.local/share/data/Mega\ Limited/`

And start MEGA application again.